# So im developing a code on python and i keep getting this error "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple' "

Tags: python

code:

```
def main():
           incomefile = open(r'C:\Users\jacey\income.txt', 'w')

           income1 = int(input("Please enter your current income:"))
           tax1= float(input("please enter current tax:"))
           income2 = int(input("Please enter your current income:"))
           tax2= float(input("please enter current tax:"))
           income3 = int(input("Please enter your current income:"))
           tax3= float(input("please enter current tax:"))
           income4 = int(input("Please enter your current income:"))
           tax4= float(input("please enter current tax:"))
           grossIncome= (income1+income2+income3+income4, '.2f')
           taxTotal= (tax1+tax2+tax3+tax4, '.2f')
           grossTaxes = (grossIncome*taxTotal, '.2f')
           netIncome = (grossIncome - grossTaxes, '.2f')
           
           

           incomefile.write(str(income1) +'\n')
           incomefile.write(str(tax1) +'\n')
           incomefile.write(str(income2) +'\n')
           incomefile.write(str(tax2) +'\n')
           incomefile.write(str(income3) +'\n')
           incomefile.write(str(tax3) +'\n')
           incomefile.write(str(income4) +'\n')
           incomefile.write(str(tax4) +'\n')
           incomefile.write(str(grossIncome) +'\n')

           incomefile.close()
           print('Data recorded in income.txt')

main()
           
grossTaxes = (grossIncome*taxTotal)
```

error:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple'
```

Comment: How are you expecting to multiply a tuple? What's your intention with this code?

Comment: There is some missing code. Add the needed code to make this runnable, we can't help you if we need to guess about code that you didn't include in the post.

Comment: I'm writing a program which will generate a record of net income data based on a minimum of four user inputs. Also need to record this in a txt file as well. I don't really understand how the error applies here

Answer (score 0):

when you do this:

```
grossIncome= (income1+income2+income3+income4, '.2f')
taxTotal= (tax1+tax2+tax3+tax4, '.2f')
```

it creates [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples):

> Tuples may be constructed in a number of ways:
>
> - Using a pair of parentheses to denote the empty tuple: ()
> - Using a trailing comma for a singleton tuple: a, or (a,)
> - **Separating items with commas: a, b, c or (a, b, c)**
> - Using the tuple() built-in: tuple() or tuple(iterable)

Then this:

```
grossTaxes = (grossIncome*taxTotal)
```

is trying to multiply those tuples. That doesn't work.

What are you trying to do with the syntax `(val+val2+val3...., '.2f')` ? Just add up the values, leave out the `'.2f'` and parenthesis: `tax=val1+val2+val3....`